# waf failed on freeBSD - Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: freebsd, waf, traceback

I am trying to run a waf on freeBSD 7.1
But it fails as:-

```
junos-olive# ./waf
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "./waf", line 148, in <<module>module>
junos-olive#
```

The line 148 is :-

```
    147:import Scripting
    148:Scripting.prepare(t, cwd, VERSION, wafdir)
    149:sys.exit(0)
```

please help

Comment: waf version? anything more? did you tripplecheck your syntax?

Comment: What version of Python are you running, what waf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies, the problem was python version.
I had installed python via macports, but i dont know why, it installed a very old python. When i updated it, everything started working.